# RStudio "Source on Save" button missing

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm having an issue where my "Source on Save" button has disappeared from RStudio, and it's really frustrating me. It was there yesterday, but now it's not. Does anyone have any idea what could be the cause of this?

The only thing I can figure out is that the button shows up BEFORE you save a new file. Once you save it, the button disappears. I've also tried updating RStudio, with no luck. Then I tried uninstalling/re-installing. Again, with no luck.

I have no idea what might have caused it to disappear since yesterday. I've been writing some code for one of my personal projects, but nothing crazy.

I'm running RStudio 0.98.977(now) on Win7.

This is really frustrating. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

edit: Also, I tried uploading a screenshot, but SO won't let. All of the file extensions are .R, so they SHOULD be interpreted correctly. Also, this behavior is consistent across all of my R scripts, including ones that previously worked correctly.

Comment: Don't really have a solution for that as I do not seem to have that problem on Linux... maybe you want to file a bug report? Otherwise CTRL+SHIFT+Enter is a handy combination ;)

Comment: @nico Thanks for the advice; I'm not familiar with that one because I used to just use CTRL+S, and the files would be sourced. However, something odd happened when I did CTRL+SHIFT+Enter. Instead of sourcing my file, RStudio launched a ShinyApp that I was playing around with, about a week ago. What's up with that? I tried clicking "Terminate App", but apparently there were no application deployments found.

Comment: If you look in the "Code" menu, you should have: "Source" (CTRL+SHIFT+S) and "Source with echo" (CTRL+SHIFT+Enter). Maybe the shortcuts are OS-specific?

Comment: Hmm...that's really strange. Even when I click on "Source with Echo" it loads up my ShinyApp. It must be stuck in memory somewhere.

Comment: I finally figured it out, thanks to this short discussion (which was just answered 2 hours ago, lucky me!): 
https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/202788856-Problem-sourcing-non-shiny-R-code-in-RStudio-0-98-953

Apparently, shiny.ui and shiny.server cannot be located in the same folder as any of the files you want to source or else it thinks all of the other files in that folder are part of the Shiny app. I guess this throws it off somehow. I still don't know why it just showed up today....but whatever, it works now.

Comment: Sorry this is causing confusion--we'll look to improve this soon!

Comment: @kendaop: so... is the source button problem gone then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured it out, thanks to this short discussion (which was just answered 2 hours ago, lucky me!): 
https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/202788856-Problem-sourcing-non-shiny-R-code-in-RStudio-0-98-953

Apparently, shiny.ui and shiny.server cannot be located in the same folder as any of the files you want to source or else it thinks all of the other files in that folder are part of the Shiny app. I guess this throws it off somehow. I still don't know why it just showed up today, because I haven't used that app in the last several days, and I've been working on projects non-stop since then....but whatever, it works now.

Hopefully, this helps someone else out in the future.

Comment: The content on the page from the above link has been removed. Can you kindly post the solution here on this page?