# RStudio "Source on Save" button missing in some scripts but not others

Tags: r, rstudio

Yes, I am aware that there is a previous question of this name from 9 years ago. The answer is not usable. ([RStudio "Source on Save" button missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24834701/rstudio-source-on-save-button-missing))

My "Source on Save" checkbox is not available for one (but not several other) R scripts. This is the checkbox that is normally next to the Save button on RStudio (Version 2023.06.1+524 (2023.06.1+524))

It was there, now it's not. All of the R scripts are a set of functions, so "Source on Save" simply runs the functions (and associated unit tests) and makes them available on the console (this is why I find it useful).

I can source just fine using CTRL-SHIFT-S. I can open other scripts (all `.R` extensions) that are similarly formatted and the "Source on Save" checkbox is there and works fine. Completely empty and new R scripts have the "Source on Save" checkbox and it works fine. It's just the one script. I cannot find any relevant options to re-implement the checkbox.

Extra context: Terminating R and restarting does not solve this. Quitting the RStudio session does not solve this. I am loading an R script with File>Open File. There is no project and I do not save the session on quitting.If you can't provide any sort of details to reproduce this issue. Renaming the file and restarting does not solve the problem.

I am reasonably certain this is an **RStudio** issue and not an R issue.

Extra context: The presence of a `testthat` unit test **which is commented out** is enough to cause the "Source on Save" checkbox to disappear. I was hoping for a quick solution on SO but this seems to be an RStudio bug so will have submitted a bug report (https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/13454):

**System details**

RStudio Edition : Desktop
RStudio Version : 2023.06.1+524 (2023.06.1+524)
OS Version      : MacOS 13.4.1 (c) (22F770820d)
R Version       :  4.2.0 (2022-04-22)

**Steps to reproduce the problem**

Open a new R script (File > Open File)
Check "Source on Save" checkbox
Save empty file ("Source on Save" checkbox remains)
Add to script:

```
library(testthat)
# test_that("an empty test", {
# })
```

Save file ("Source on Save" checkbox disappears)

**Describe the problem in detail**

"Source on Save" checkbox disappears when any unit test (even if commented out) exists in the script and the script is saved.

**Describe the behavior you expected**

"Source on Save" checkbox remains when any unit test (even if commented out) exists in the script and the script is saved.

Comment: Are you sure the File has an .R extension. Can you provide any steps to create a reproducible example? If you create a new file and copy the contents in, can you save on source there? Is it about the file contents or the specific file itself?

Comment: If you can't provide any sort of details to reproduce this issue, then I suggest you ask for help at the RStudio support site: https://community.rstudio.com/ or file a GitHub issue with the project: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues. But I'm sure they'll ask for more details as well. Can you copy/email the file to another computer? Does it still have the same behavior? Can you rename the file on disk?

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick, I am aware of and appreciate the need for a repex in most situations. I don't think this is one of them, because likely this is an RStudio option that is hidden and I've missed. I think asking on SO if anyone knows about this missing option is perfectly legitimate. Your statement "If you can't provide any sort of details to reproduce this issue" isn't really accurate, as I have provided as much relevant detail as I can. But thank you for your suggestions. Those sites generally do not provide timely or useful information, which is why I am here.

Comment: Renaming the file on disk does not solve the problem.

Comment: Corrected response: Are you sure the File has an .R extension. **Yes** Can you provide any steps to create a reproducible example? **No, that's the problem, but see Github issue.** If you create a new file and copy the contents in, can you save on source there? **No but empty files are fine**

Comment: Is it about the file contents or the specific file itself **I don't see anything different about the specific file that is different from other files with similar structure, which is why I am still not convinced that the repex I have provided is actually a repex because I have had scripts where the unit tests are in the scripts before and all was well**

Answer (score 0):

Partial solution:
RStudio Version 2023.06.1+524 (2023.06.1+524) appears to remove the availability of the "Source on Save" checkbox for a script if any `testthat` unit test is present in the script, **even if the unit test is commented out**.

A partial solution is to remove all unit tests to a separate file and source that file in the original R script. Unit tests are then run appropriately when "Source on Save" is checked and the file saved using the "Save" button.

Comment: But you said if you copied the contents to a new file, you could still save on source. So if it was about testthat code, shouldn’t that still cause the problem? Or was that not true?

Comment: I was mistaken. I created a new file but did not copy the contents in. Mistakes happen. Given that I have corrected the mistake, provided context, submitted an RStudio bug report and identified the problem and suggested a solution, can you please explain why this contribution deserves a downvote, or remove it?

Comment: I’m glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

My "Source on Save" checkbox was missing suddenly.
I remembered that I changed some options. After unchecking
"Automaticly save when Editor looses focus" under
Tools/Global Options/Code/Saving
the "Source on Save" checkbox was back!

Hope that helps others with similar problems.